# What are the best/most popular libraries for Json schema validation and serializing/serializing into objects in Node.js?

Tags: json, node.js, express

What are the best/most popular libraries for Json schema validation and serializing/serializing into objects in Node.js or express.js?

Answer (score 0):

you can use validation libraries like https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4, but express and node work with json objects out of the box.